# Using search box in ArcGIS map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online-basemaps

Following is my UI for map

[image]

There's a searchbox and a pin.

When I search for a location, let's say McDonald's, I get list of suggestions

[image]

when I click on one of the suggestions, it doesn't do anything, no service call happens to get me to the location I chose.

But when I use keyboard to select, (up/down arrow keys)and hit enter on a suggestion, map does take me to that location.

Am I doing something wrong?

Update on new Findings
Its not triggering 'select-result' on search object when I click. but does trigger when I use keyboard to select one of suggestions.

Comment: @S P, I didn't get what do you mean by using the keyboard to select, can you please add some more info, as you have involved ArcGIS map, adding a few screenshots can make it understandable.

Comment: Are you using the Locate tool of ArcGIS Pro or something else?

Comment: I have edited the question , added better description.
I am using community version of Arc GIS